# searching on issue assigned on me in GitHub api

Tags: github, github-pages, github-api

I am using GitHub rest api v3. I am aware that using search api https://developer.github.com/v3/search/#search-issues we can query issues in GitHub. 
However, I am interested in querying the issue which is created or assigned to me.

(i.e) Repository = xxxxxxxxx
https://api.github.com/user/issues -> using this i can get the issues assigned to me, but i want to get the issues which has the state as open.

How can i query this, also let me know other possible ways for querying.

Comment: I am not sure I understand your question. Do you want to find issues that are created by you `OR` assigned to you `AND` is open ?

Comment: https://api.github.com/user/issues this will retrieve this

Answer (score 0):

GitHub just announced (January 2020, 2+ years later):

"[Search by @me](https://github.blog/changelog/2020-01-20-search-by-me/)"

> You can now create and share search queries that **resolve to the current user** by using the **`@me`** search syntax.
>
> For example, navigating to https://github.com/search?q=is%3Aissue+state%3Aopen+assignee%3A%40me (when logged into GitHub) will return all the open issues that are assigned to you.
>
> You can also type `assignee:@me is:issue state:open` into any search field to return the same results.